# how to create button click event for form method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Form tag in my layout page. I cant use form tags in content page, so I am using Form method="post" how to create button click event for this and how to give validation for html input type?

```
<form class="contact-form-title white" method="post">
    <label id="lblFirstName" runat="server" title="First Name:">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFirstNam" runat="server"  /><br />

    <label id="lblLastName" runat="server" title="Last Name:">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtLastNam" runat="server"  /><br />

    <label id="lblEmail" runat="server" title="Email ID:">Email ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtEmail" runat="server"  />

    <label id="lblMessage" runat="server" title="Message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="txtMessag" runat="server" ></textarea><br />                          
    <input type="submit" class="btn delicious f-center" runat="server" id="btnContac" name="SUBMIT" onserverclick="btnContac_Click" style="height:25%; width:10%;"/>
</form>
```

Back-End :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnContac_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string FirstName = txtFirstNam.Value;
   string LastName = txtLastNam.Value;
   string EmailID = txtEmail.Value;
   string Message = txtLastNam.Value;
}
```

Comment: I guess I do not understand... As I can see you get a postback on click and can read values from input fields. What the problem is?

Comment: is this asp.net or mvc?

Comment: @AnilKumar asp.net

Comment: the code is not working? is it reaching btnContac_Click ?

Comment: so you do not want to use server control, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e83792/asp-net-server-controls/ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 : client side control** 
In Code behind use ispostback to catch the post back event,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // write form population code;
        }
        else
        {
            //you will get posted data here;
        }
}
```

to validate on client side, write your own java script validator something on below line.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() 
    {
var Firstname = document.getElementById('txtFirstNam').value
if (Firstname == "") 
{
    alert("Enter First Name");
    return false;
}

if (LastName == "") {
    alert("Enter Last Name");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

then call this validator on submit button click

```
<input type="submit" class="btn delicious f-center" runat="server" id="btnContac" name="SUBMIT" onclick="return validate();" style="height:25%; width:10%;"/>
```

**Option 2 : Server side control**

Change all input and button into server controls (add `runat=server`) controls into server , then you can catch the event on server side in code behind like you are trying to do. [good place](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e83792/asp-net-server-controls/) to start

In server side approach, you have chance to use built in validators.

```
ASP.NET provides the following validation controls:
RequiredFieldValidator.
RangeValidator.
CompareValidator.
RegularExpressionValidator.
CustomValidator.
ValidationSummary.
```

for validator refer [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/validation-controls-in-asp-net/)